# Proving the Pythagorean theorem using four right triangles arranged around a square

Tags: geometry, proof-verification

> The diagram shows a square and four congruent right angled triangles.
>   Use the diagram to prove that $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$

I know that the area of the larger square is $a^2 + 2ab +b^2$ and the area of all the four triangles altogether is $\frac{4ab}{2}$

Thank You and Help is appreciated

[image]

Comment: I have suppressed the tags 'linear-algebra" : no vectors, no matrices here... and "pythagorean-triples" because  $a,b,c$ aren't asked to be **integers**.

Comment: This is very classical : see proof #4 in https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The area of the large square is $(a+b)^2$. The total area of the $4$ right triangles is $4\cdot \frac{ab}{2}=2ab$. Also I have $c^2+2ab=(a+b)^2$. Expanding, I have: $c^2+2ab=a^2+b^2+2ab$ and so $c^2=a^2+b^2$.

Answer (score 2):

What have you tried?

**Hint**

- can you calculate the area of the total (large) square, in terms of $a$ and $b$?
- what is the area of the four (blue) right triangles?
- what is the area of the inner (white) square?

Comment: area of the large square is 2b + 2a

Comment: area of four right triangles is $4ab/2$

Comment: For the large square: check this again. The length of one side is ... so the **area** is (...)²

Comment: o nvm its a square the area is $(ab)^2$

Comment: Check again! The length of one side is not $ab$ but ...

Comment: O sorry $a^2 +2ab + b^2$

Comment: and the area of the inner square is $c^2$

Comment: You got the correct answer for my 3 questions; now: which parts should add up to which total? Look at the diagram!

Comment: The area of the inner square plus the area of the total of the four triangles equals the area of the larger square.

Comment: O so $2ab + c^2$ = $a^2 + b^2 + 2ab$ so $c^2$ must equal $a^2$ + $b^2$

Comment: Correct! Next time: take some time to think a bit longer on your own and include your work/ideas in your question.

Comment: Thank You for helping me! Yes I will definitely try to do a question myself before asking c: